# New BUG in Winter 19: We can't turn ON Country State Picklists on fresh new Orgs (Confirmed as Know Issue by Salesforce)

Tags: data, configuration, setup, country-and-state

We turn on Country-State-Picklists on almost every Org we touch.

Assume we act on a NEW and BLANK Org, just fresh spun DE (Developer Edition) Org. But it is the same on any Org and we have tried lots of Orgs within the last 2 day... So rest assured, that the following is NOT related to any strange configuration or to bad data. We cleaned everything, i.e on the Orgs we have the issues there are

- 0 (zero!) records of Contact, Account, Lead, Contract, Opportunity, Lead, Task, Event
- we deleted all custom fields and all custom objects
- we deleted as much as we could (page layouts, etc)

Until now, we followed the work list provided here:
yourMyDomain/i18n/AddressCleanerOverview.apexp?setupid=AddressCleanerOverview

[image]

Usually it's done from top to bottom and works.

Now with Winter'19 not anymore. At step 2 we scan and for sure fix everything we got as feedback. Then we scan again. Feedback come back clean. But if we proceed to step 3, we get

> You must perform a scan of your data and customizations before you can
>   map values to state and country/territory picklist values.

Which leads us back to step 2 - effectively creating an endless loop.

So we can never complete step 3 - hence never activate the country state picklists.

What is going on here? This looks like a severe Salesforce Bug in Winter 19.

---

**UPDATE 1 (2018-10-31)**

I got Feedback by Salesforce support:

> I want to inform you that, the issue you are facing is a multicustomer
>   issue and many other customers are facing it. The higher team are
>   working on this issue. Will give you an update as soon as we get from
>   the higher team.

**UPDATE 2 (2018-11-02)**

> We have an update from R&D and this has been termed as a Bug.Known
>   Issue link :
>   https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=cannot-enable-state-and-country-picklists-on-a-developer-org&Id=a1p3A00000031hg
>
> As of now there is No ETA on this. This is in review status and
>   probably we should get this addressed soon as the days go by - based
>   on the impact and the users affected count.

Comment: Have you received the email confirmation that the Scan in #2 is complete, I would assume so, just cross checking. If even after that you are not able to proceed, you may like to raise a case to the support then.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox and yes I do have received the email and the case to the support is already raised. The issue is also perfectly reproducible on all orgs I've touched today, which were about 5 DE Orgs. So as it stands, it seems impossible to turn this feature on in general on any org since winter 19.

Comment: I'm still facing this issue in winter'19 org. Do you have any workaround or solution of this issue?

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj no solution yet - waiting on support. this is a very very very serious salesforce bug. I would recommend, that you open a case with support, too. all my support cases are in high risk to get closed, because I have no premier support and they try to flag them as Developer Support - even if its about BUGs... :-(

Comment: Alright! I just asked the question on partner community. I'll open the case very soon. Please keep posted if you get any update.

Comment: @AnuragBhardwaj yes, same for you: any hints, updates, intermediate results are welcome

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I only receive the first email about the customizations having been scanned but do not receive the second email to say the data scan has completed. I tried re-running several times. Tried adding a new account and rescanning, tried adding a dummy country and rescanning, tried updating the country of an existing account but still cannot complete the scan (step #3). Error as above: You must perform a scan of your data and customizations before you can map values to state and country/territory picklist values. I aslo tried raising a ticket via Trailhead but after a

Comment: FWIW, if you can provide this repro in a fresh dev org (with no custom apex) to support, it might help.

Comment: The "Scan Now" page lists the dates of the last scans, right? Do the dates match what you expect?

Comment: @CarolynGrabill I'm trying to figure that out with the support, but this is a slow process... at scan now, there is NO list of the last scans. But surprisingly we receive the confirmation email, that the scan is finished. So it look like a BUG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce has fixed the known issue in latest patch

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=cannot-enable-state-and-country-picklists-on-a-developer-org&Id=a1p3A00000031hg

Please check on respective orgs.

Answer (score 1):

I reported this issue to Salesforce too. They were very prompt in responding and sent me the message below. Anybody with similar issues can use the link to stay notified when resolved.

*I would like to keep you posted that, the unexpected behavior is noted as the bug and R&D team is working on the fix towards it. Please find the known issue details below where you can click on the button "This issue affects me" and you will be notified once the issue is resolved.*

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=cannot-enable-state-and-country-picklists-on-a-developer-org&Id=a1p3A00000031hgo